# search post api return null with flutter http package

Tags: laravel, flutter, api, http-post

this the function for API in laravel for search:

```
   public function search(Request $request) {
        try {
            $request->validate(['search' => ['max:15', 'required']]);
            $search = $request->input('search');
            $answerSearch = Answer::where('title','like', '%'.$search.'%')->get();
            return AnswersResource::collection($answerSearch);

        }catch(\Exception $e){
            return response()->json(['status'=>false, 'msg'=> $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }
}
```

in postman it works like a charm and expected

but with the flutter this is the code to work with this API:

```
  Future<List<AnswerData>> searchAnswers({required String search}) async {
    final response = await post(
    Uri.parse("$_url/search"),
    headers:  <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{"search" : search})
    );
    final answers = answerFromJson(response.body);
    print("fdfsdfdsfdsf ${answers.data}");
    return answers.data;
  }
}
```

its return null ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the response status by printing 'response.statusCode'.

```
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
```

Comment: show me 500 , but still work on postman?

Comment: The HTTP status code 500 is a generic error response. It means that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. This error is usually returned by the server when no other error code is suitable.